# How to get a Resource from a project inside a library project

Tags: android, android-resources

Here is the situation: I Have two projects. Let's say a `LibraryProject` and a `MainProject`. The `MainProject` references the `LibraryProject` as a library.

I have one activity in the `LibraryProject` that needs to discover if the `MainProject` have defined a specific drawable, let's say "logo.png" (Think that the logo image must be defined by each `MainProject, and not by the LibraryProject.

How to, in one activity of the `LibraryProject`, discover if the `MainProject` has this image in the `res/drawable` folder?

Obviouslly I have tried to see if  `R.drawable.logo != 0` (or variation of it), but as you know, this line will not compile, since the image is not in the `res/drawable` folder of the `LibraryProject`.

I also tried `getResources().getIdentifier("logo", "drawable", null) != 0` but this boolean expression is always returning false, since the `.getIdentifier()` always returns zero.

Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this: (but remember, the context is always "ChildProject")

```
public static Drawable getDrawable(Context context, String resource_name){
    try{
        int resId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(resource_name, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
        if(resId != 0){
            return context.getResources().getDrawable(resId);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG,"getDrawable - resource_name: "+resource_name);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked! I did not realize that the context would be from the MainProject and not from de LibraryProject

Comment: How do i get the context from the library project ?

Comment: Important: Context must be initialized to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a default resource in the Library Project. If there is an identically named resource in your `MainProject`, it will override the Library Project resource.

For example, if you provide "res/drawable/logo.png" in both projects, then `R.drawable.logo` in the Library Project will use the "logo.png" image that is in the "res/drawable" folder of the MainProject.

---

*This answer does not address how the Library Project should discover if the Main Project has a resource, only how to force use of it, if there is one.*

Comment: I agree with you, but this is exactilly what I don't want because if the MainProject does not define a resource, the resource of the LibraryProject will be shown and I don't want this. If the MainProject does not provide the resource I want to know and do anything else.

Comment: Perhaps there is promise in @Dale's answer. It would take some experimenting, but I would follow that route if I were in your shoes. Another method would be to make a very small default resource and store a signature, such as byte size, in your app so that you can test if the Library Project default resource was found. Otherwise, a Main Project resource would be present.

Answer (score 0):

Have your main project pass a Context to the library, and call context.getString().